# Programmatic login based on JDBCRealm

Tags: authentication, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, jaas, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to implement OpenID authentication in a simple JSP app.

The `FORM`-based authentication really drives me nuts, since there is no way to listen for *pre*, *post*-authenticate events.

When I receive user information from OpenID-provider I want to suggest them to fill out simple registration form (i.e. edit details received from identity provider, and optionally add some additional information). But if I use standard "j_security_check" action, those details are lost. If I try to log in user programmatically (i.e. using HttpServletRequest#login(user, password) I can't redirect the user to the originally requested URL (since only `FormAuthenticator` keeps this information).

Is there a way to manually control authentication mechanism, using some pre-configured JDBC realm? That is, I don't want to specify `<login-config />` in my web.xml, but when calling HttpServletRequest#login I want to authenticate against JDBC realm. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, that is basically not possible with what GlassFish offers ootb.
You need to dig deeper. You would end up using a custom JAAS LoginModule and the JSR-196 Login Bridge.
Some more pointers:

- http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/gf-and-generic-jaas-loginmodule?force=316
- https://blogs.oracle.com/nasradu8/entry/loginmodule_bridge_profile_jaspic_in